# Create matrix from combinational arrangement of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, vector, vector-calculus

I am just trying to produce a short hand code which shall do the following:

I have a function of 2 vectors $f(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$

```
f=#1^2+#2^2-#3-#4&;
```

and vectors $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}$ of the shape

```
v1={1,2};
v2={2,3};
```

as well as weights $w_1, w_2$

```
w1=1/4;
w2=3/4;
```

and I need to calculate the sum of all sets of possible combinations

```
w1*w1*f@@v1~Join~v1 + w1*w2*f@@v1~Join~v2 + w2*w1*f@@v2~Join~v1 + w2*w2*f@@v2~Join~v2
```

Is there a short hand notation for this? Like creating a matrix from all combinations of {v1,v2} and apply that matrix to the function?

In my real function I have 3d vectors instead of 2d vectors and there are 20 vectors instead of 2. I obviously don't want to write down all combinations by hand.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like a job for `Outer`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Total[
 Times[
  KroneckerProduct[{w1, w2}, {w1, w2}],
  Outer[
    {x, y} \[Function] F @@ Join[x, y],
    {v1, v2},
    {v1, v2},
    1
    ]
 ],
 2]
```

> 1/16 F[1, 2, 1, 2] + 3/16 F[1, 2, 2, 3] + 3/16 F[2, 3, 1, 2] +   9/16
>   F[2, 3, 2, 3]

And for your final application, this might go well:

```
n = 20;
vectors = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 3}];
weights = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
Total[
 Times[
  KroneckerProduct[weights, weights],
  Outer[{x, y} \[Function] F @@ Join[x, y], vectors, vectors, 1]
  ],
 2]
```

If you define `F` such with only two vector arguments (and access the components in the body by `[[ ... ]]`) then simply

```
Total[KroneckerProduct[weights, weights], Outer[F, vectors, vectors, 1]], 2]
```

will also do.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Henrik Schumacher the `"outer"-solution is

```
{W1, W2}.Outer[F[##] &, {V1, V2}, {V1, V2}].{W1, W2}
(*W1^2 F[V1, V1] + W1 W2 F[V1, V2] + W1 W2 F[V2, V1] + W2^2 F[V2, V2] *)
```